# Difference between exp() expf() and __expf() in CUDA

Tags: cuda

How to optimize the exp function in CUDA?
What are the differences between the following in CUDA?

```
exp()
expf()
__expf()
```

Comment: This is all covered in Appendix C of the CUDA programming guide, just like several of your earlier CUDA related questions. Perhaps now is the time to read the documentation?

Comment: It is now covered in [Appendix D](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#mathematical-functions-appendix) . I know this is going to change again sometime.

Comment: I liked his question though, googling and finding on stackoverflow beats hoping to find anything in cuda documentation imho

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The differences are explained in the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#mathematical-functions-appendix), appendix D.

- `exp()` should be used for double precision, although should be overloaded for single
- `expf()` should be used for single precision (`float`)
- `__expf()` is the fast-math version, the performance is faster with some loss of precision (dependent on the input value, see the [guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#mathematical-functions-appendix) for more details).

Comment: is The maximum ulp error is `2 + floor(abs(1.16 * x))` according to the link. You may want to add that to your answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Generally `exp()` is for doubles, `expf()` for floats and both are slightly slower than `__exp()` which is available as a hardware operation. The performance gain usually comes at the cost of accuracy but unless you are really concerned about accuracy it shouldn't be a problem.