# Does Shader Unit calculates exponent

Tags: cuda

http://us.hardware.info/reviews/5419/nvidia-geforce-gtx-titan-z-sli-review-incl-tones-tizair-system
 says that "GTX Titan-Z" has 5760 Shader units. Also here is written that "GTX Titan-Z" has 2x GK110 GPU.

[CUDA exp() expf() and __expf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257843/cuda-exp-expf-and-expf) mentiones that it is possible to calculate exponent in cuda.

Let's say I have array of 500 000 000 ( five hundred millions ) of doubles. I want to calculate exponents of each of value in array. Who knows what to expect: 5760 shader units will be able to calculate exp, or this task can be done only with two GK110 GPU? Difference in perfomance is drastical, so I need to be sure, that if I rewrite my app with CUDA, then it will not work slower.

In other words, can I make 5760 threads to calculate 500 000 000 exponents?

Comment: `exp2f()` is the only exponentiation with direct support in hardware. Depending on compilation mode there may still be a thin wrapper code for `exp2f()` as the hardware has no support for denormal operands. All other exponentiation is performed via software subroutines. A Tesla K20 can execute on the order of 25e9 double-precision `exp()` calls per second. If you compute only DP `exp()` for each array element and nothing else, your code will be bound by memory bandwidth, not `exp()` throughput: each `exp()` requires 16 bytes of data (8 in, 8 out) so total 400 GB/sec which exceeds HW specs

Comment: @njuffa if you want to provide an answer, I would upvote.

Comment: @Robert Crovella Thanks for the endorsement. I am waiting for feedback from the asker to see whether my comments actually address the question, since the question was not entirely clear to me.

Comment: What is HW? Algorithm is more complicated, I just need to know which cores will work for exp: 5760 shader units or 2 GPUs ? Or in another words, can I make 5750 threads to calculate 500 000 000 exponents?

Comment: HW = hardware (there is a length restriction on comments and HW is a commonly-used abbreviation). You can have any number of threads compute those 500,000,000 DP `exp()` values, the mapping of threads to array elements is entirely up to you. It has nothing to do with the number of CUDA cores or the number of GPUs, but if you want to process 500M array elements in one go, you will need to fit them into the memory attached to the GPU, so 4 GB worth of input and 4 GB worth of output for double precision.

Comment: "GTX Titan-Z" has 13 Gb, so it is more then enough space even for another 250M. Question is not about memory. Question is which part of "GTX Titan-Z" can calculate exp: "Shader unit" or GPU? Because number of threads depends from number of processing units. If "Shader Unit" can't calculate exp, then for my task "GTX Titan-Z" is worthless

Comment: There seems to be some confusion when you ask "shader unit or GPU?". The GTX Titan-Z is a dual GPU card. Each Titan-Z sports two GK110 GPUs, each with it own attached 6 GB of memory. Each GK110 on the card has 2880 execution units called "CUDA cores". Just like a CPU, the GPU's execution units can process integer, single-precision floating point, and double-precision floating point operations, such as addition, multiplication etc. DP `exp()` in CUDA is implemented as a subroutine in terms of those operations. You can see the source code in file math_functions_dbl_ptx3.h that comes with CUDA.

Comment: The execution units in GK110 are grouped into clusters called SMX. Each GK110 on the GTX Titan Z has fifteen SMX clusters, each SMX comprises 192 single-precision units and 64 double-precision units (plus an assortment of other units). See the block diagram in [NVIDIA's GK110 whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf). Each DP unit can process one FMA (fused multiply-add) operation per clock cycle. Each GK110 on Titan Z @ 705 MHz base clock can execute 676.8e9 DP FMAs per second = 1.3536 DP TFLOPS, entire card thus 2.7072 DP TFLOPS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GTX Titan Z is a dual GPU device. Each of the two GK110 GPUs on the card is attached via a 384-bit memory interface to its own 6 GB of high-speed memory. The theoretical bandwidth of each memory is 336 GB/sec. The particular GK110 variant used in the GTX Titan Z is comprised of fifteen clusters of execution units called SMX. Each SMX in turn is comprised of 192 single-precision floating-point units, 64 double-precision floating point units, and various other units.

Each double-precision unit in GK110 can execute one FMA (fused multiply-add), or one FMUL, or one FADD per clock cycle. At a base clock of 705 MHz, the maximum total number of DP operations that can be executed by each of the GK110 GPUs on Titan Z per second is therefore 705e6 * 15 * 64 = 676.8e9. Assuming all operations are FMAs, that equates to 1.3536 double-precision TFLOPS. Since the card uses two GPUs, the total DP performance of a GTX Titan Z is thus 2.7072 TFLOPS.

Like CPUs, GPUs provide general-purpose computation via various integer and floating-point units. GPUs also provide special function units (called MUFU = **mu**lti**fu**nction unit on GK110) that can compute rough single-precision approximations to some frequently used functions such as reciprocal, reciprocal square root, sine, cosine, exponential base 2, and logarithm based 2. As far as exponentiation is concerned, the standard single-precision math function `exp2f()` is the only function that maps more or less directly to a MUFU instruction (`MUFU.EX2`). Depending on compilation mode, there is a thin wrapper around this hardware instruction since the hardware does not support denormal operands in the special function units.

All other exponentiaton in CUDA is performed via software subroutines. The standard single-precision function `expf()` is a fairly heavy-weight wrapper around the hardware's `exp2` capability. The double-precision `exp()` function is a pure software routine based on minimax polynomial approximation. The complete source code for it is visible in the CUDA header file `math_functions_dbl_ptx3.h` (in CUDA 6.5, DP `exp()` code starts at line 1706 in that file). As you can see, the computation involves primarily double-precision floating-point operations, as well as integer and some single-precision floating-point operations. You can also look at the machine code by disassembling a binary executable that calls `exp()` with `cuobjdump --dump-sass`.

In terms of performance, in CUDA 6.5 the double precision `exp()` function has a throughput on the order of 25e9 function calls per second on a Tesla K20 (1.170 DP TFLOPS). Since each call to DP `exp()` consumes an 8-byte source operand and produces an 8-byte result, this equates to roughly 400 GB/sec of memory bandwidth. Since each GK110 on a Titan Z provides about 15% more performance than the GK110 on a Tesla K20, the throughput and bandwidth requirements increase accordingly. Since the required bandwidth exceeds the theoretical memory bandwidth of the GPU, code that simply applies DP `exp()` to an array will be completely bound by memory bandwidth.

The number of functional units in the GPU and the number of threads executing has no relationship with the number of array elements that can be processed, but can have an impact on the performance of such processing. The mapping of array elements to threads can be freely chosen by the programmer. The number of array elements that can be processed in one go is a function of the size of the GPU's memory. Note that not all of the raw memory on the device is available for user code as the CUDA software stack needs some memory for its own use, typically around 100 MB or so. An exemplary mapping for applying DP `exp()` to an array is shown in this code snippet:

```
__global__ void exp_kernel (const double * __restrict__ src, 
                            double * __restrict__ dst, int len)
{
    int stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    for (int i = tid; i < len; i += stride) {
        dst[i] = exp (src[i]);
    }
}    

#define ARRAY_LENGTH (500000000)
#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK  (256)
int main (void) {
    // ...
    int len = ARRAY_LENGTH;
    dim3 dimBlock(THREADS_PER_BLOCK);
    int threadBlocks = (len + (dimBlock.x - 1)) / dimBlock.x;
    if (threadBlocks > 65520) threadBlocks = 65520;
    dim3 dimGrid(threadBlocks);
    double *d_a = 0, *d_b = 0;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, sizeof(d_a[0]), len);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b, sizeof(d_b[0]), len);
    // ...
    exp_kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_a, d_b, len);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: DP stands for double precision?

Comment: Yes. DP = double precision, SP = single precision are commonly used abbreviations.